# Is there any short cut to check the infinite differentiability of given function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+y\neq -1\}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^2$,
>   Define $f(x,y)=({x\over 1+x+y},{y\over 1+x+y})$,Then Check whether the
>   function is infinite differentiable or not?

My attempt

**method-1** 
If $f$ is infinitely differentiable iff Each component of $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Each component of $f$ is a rational function of two variable. denominator never vanishes. So, $f$ is one-time differentiable.

**method- 2**

$${h\over 1+h+k}-0=0.h+0.k+\sqrt{h^2+k^2}r(h,k)$$. We can easily prove that $\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}r(h,k)=0$. Similarly for other component. Is there any short cut to check the infinite differentiability of given function?

**method- 3**
I tried to use the definition of the differentiability in the higher dimension. I couldn't find the corresponding linear map for each element in $A$. How do I found such linear transformation to prove the differentiability? If I define $T(x,y)=\frac{\partial(f_1,f_2)}{\partial(x,y)}(x,y)^t. $ Will it be fine? This is just the first derivative. How can I prove the existance of highere derivatives? Please help me.

Comment: Showing differentiability won't establish $C^\infty$. You want to use well-known facts of standard functions whenever you look for $C^\infty$.

Comment: thank you @TedShifrin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rational function with denominator nonzero on open set $A$ is $C^\infty$ on $A$.  This follows by induction from the fact that it is once differentiable and the derivative is rational with denominator that is nonzero on $A$.

Comment: How do I find the first derivative of $f(x,y)$?Is it same as J.(x,y)^t?